# Map nginx defualt port to a different port

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, nginx-reverse-proxy

Hi I am running NGINX server on Redhat UBI Image. I would like to run the nginx server on a different  port like port 81. I have made changes to my dockerfile and nginx.conf file and mapped to port 81. But nginx does not start up port 81.

Any solutions?

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi8-minimal


RUN microdnf --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install -y nginx procps net-tools ca-certificates dirmngr gnupg wget vim\
            && microdnf clean all \
            && rpm -q procps-ng

#COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

#To start up NGINX 
EXPOSE 81

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Here is nginx.conf file that i have mapped to port 81 but i cannot seem to get it the nginx working on my localhost

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 81;
        server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        set  $allowOriginSite *;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;


        #ENV_ACCESS_LOG
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    location /search/ {
         proxy_pass http://**********:8983/****/;   
    }
    location /test/ {
         proxy_pass http://*****:8080/****/;    
    }
     }
}
```

Comment: How are you starting the container?

Comment: i am trying to run my container on my docker-compose file

Answer (score 0):

To map the port from the container to your host, you must start the container with the "--publish" (or "-p") option (cf. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/).

In your case it should be :

```
docker run -p 81:81 <your_image>
```

*Where the first "81" is the port you would like to use to access the container from your host, and the second "81" is the port nginx is listening on the container*

Comment: (The port numbers do not need to be the same, and with the default nginx configuration you can use `-p 81:80` to publish to a different port.)

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that locally it works but i am trying to deploy on my helm charts and Nginx does not start on port 81